# EC2 Instance not responding state repeatedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, latency

Our EC2 instance are going to not responding every 15-20 minutes after which I have to restart the app servers with the following information on the EBS dashboard:

1. No data received from the instance. Last seen 10 minutes ago.
2. Instance EBS health state has been "OutOfService" for 62 seconds: Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively.
3. None of the instances are sending data.
4. EBS health is failing or not available for all instances.

We observer the following metric:

1. Environment Health - Severe
2. Average Latency - 60+ seconds
3. Sum Requests - 150-200/minute
4. CPU Utilisation - 20-40%
5. DB Connections - 6-8
6. DB CPU Utilisation - 2%

Few things I tried - 
 1. Tried playing around with security groups, no luck yet. Also the slow query logs look normal.
 2. Can't SSH or access the EC2 directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "going down"? Are they simply not responding, or are they being terminated? Also, did you mean "ELB" rather than "EBS"? (Feel free to edit the question to correct.) First thing to do is to try and access an EC2 instance directly (not via the Load Balancer) and see if it responds. If not, login to the instance and diagnose what is happening. If it _is_ working, then you should diagnose the Load Balancer health check to determine why it considers the instance(s) unhealthy.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @JohnRotenstein. I wrote the post late at night so messed up the ELB and EBS, sorry for that. I am  not able to connect to my EC2 directly or via SSH when it goes into unresponsive state.

Comment: You will need to debug what is happening with the instance. Use your standard techniques for debugging problems -- try restarting it, logging in, checking log files, check CloudWatch to see whether the CPU is idle or busy, try to determine what makes it go unresponsive. It is running software that you have configured, so you'll need to figure out what is causing the problem.